# Multiple SQL statements in SQL Developer with DB2

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer v4.1.2.20 with an IBM DB2 v10.5 database.

Why can I select and run multiple statements like this:

```
drop trigger T_MyTab1;
drop trigger T_MyTab2;
```

But If I select these 2 statements it fails:

```
create trigger T_MyTab1 after insert on MyTab1 referencing new as n for each row mode db2sql insert into MyAuditTab1 values (n.col1); 
create trigger T_MyTab2 after insert on MyTab2 referencing new as n for each row mode db2sql insert into MyAuditTab2 values (n.col1);
```

The error is:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=create trigger T_MyTab1 after inse;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<space>, DRIVER=3.69.24
```

The same SQL works fine in SquirrelSQL, so I think it's to do with the line delimiter in SQL Developer...

Comment: For Oracle statements you'd need to put a `/` delimiter on a new line after each create-trigger statement, because of the PL/SQL code. Does doing that help with DB2? Also are you running the selected code as a statement (control-enter) or as a script (F5); probably doesn't matter here but might be worth checking the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I added '/' on a new line after each create-trigger statement as you suggested and the first create statement ran perfectly, with no errors. But the second create statement seems to get completely ignored.
I tried with as both a statement and a script, with the same results.